# Changing background color of a div in click event gives unexpected (or is it expected?) result

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I'm working on a word guessing game, and when the user clicks a letter on the visual keyboard I've created, I want the background color of that letter to change (light green if correctly guessed, grey if incorrect). However, the default background (set with 'letter' class) doesn't seem to get replaced properly after clicking. Instead, an unstyled box (no border radius etc.) with the new background color overlays the default background color (it's visually obvious). I'm interested to know why this happens. Could someone please enlighten me? Is this a known phenomenon? Or is it to do with my event and use of e.target?

Please see my HTML, CSS & Javascript below.

```js
const currentWord = "abc"

$('.keyboard .row .letter').click(function(e) {
        
    // Check if 'currentWord' contains clicked letter 
    let check = [];
    currentWord.split('').forEach(function(letter, i) {

        let clickedLetter = e.target.firstChild.textContent.toLocaleUpperCase();

        if(clickedLetter === letter.toLocaleUpperCase()) {

            // Change background of correctly guessed letter
            $(e.target).css('background-color','lightgreen');

            // Make letter appear in letter box
            $(`#${letter} .word-letter`).text(clickedLetter).fadeOut(1).fadeIn(250);
            check.push(1);

        } else if((i === currentWord.length - 1) && !check.length) {

            // Change background of incorrectly guessed letter
            $(e.target).css('background-color', 'grey');
        }   
  })
})
```

```css
/* KEYBOARD */
        .keyboard {
            grid-column: 2/5;
            grid-row: 6/8;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: rgb(223, 255, 196);
        }
        
        .row {
            height: 40%;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 2em;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .letter {
            text-align: center;
            width: 5%;
            background-color: rgb(158, 228, 255);
            margin: 1%;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px lightgray;
        }
        
        .letter:hover {
            background-color: rgb(255, 138, 255);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="keyboard">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="letter"><p>Q</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>W</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>E</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>R</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>T</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>Y</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>U</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>I</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>O</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>P</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="letter"><p>A</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>S</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>D</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>F</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>G</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>H</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>J</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>K</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>L</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="letter"><p>Z</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>X</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>C</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>V</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>B</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>N</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>M</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are setting the `background-color` on `e.target` which might not be the element with the `letter` class. The event target is the element that was actually clicked and can be a child (e.g. the `p` tag). This happens because events *bubble* up the dom and trigger any listeners that they encounter. To get the element on which the event listener is attached use `e.currentTarget`

```js
const currentWord = "abc"

$('.keyboard .row .letter').click(function(e) {
        
    // Check if 'currentWord' contains clicked letter 
    let check = [];
    currentWord.split('').forEach(function(letter, i) {

        let clickedLetter = e.currentTarget.firstChild.textContent.toLocaleUpperCase();

        if(clickedLetter === letter.toLocaleUpperCase()) {

            // Change background of correctly guessed letter
            $(e.currentTarget).css('background-color','lightgreen');

            // Make letter appear in letter box
            $(`#${letter} .word-letter`).text(clickedLetter).fadeOut(1).fadeIn(250);
            check.push(1);

        } else if((i === currentWord.length - 1) && !check.length) {

            // Change background of incorrectly guessed letter
            $(e.currentTarget).css('background-color', 'grey');
        }   
  })
})
```

```css
/* KEYBOARD */
.keyboard {
    grid-column: 2/5;
    grid-row: 6/8;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgb(223, 255, 196);
}

.row {
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.letter {
    text-align: center;
    width: 5%;
    background-color: rgb(158, 228, 255);
    margin: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px lightgray;
}

        .letter:hover {
            background-color: rgb(255, 138, 255);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="keyboard">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="letter"><p>Q</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>W</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>E</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>R</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>T</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>Y</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>U</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>I</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>O</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>P</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="letter"><p>A</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>S</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>D</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>F</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>G</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>H</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>J</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>K</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>L</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="letter"><p>Z</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>X</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>C</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>V</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>B</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>N</p></div>
        <div class="letter"><p>M</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```